# Pyspark - File Not Found Exception

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I am encountering the following error while running the *spark-submit* command **only on the spark cluster mode** whereas I am getting the correct output when running locally. The error is displayed in the CMD Prompt as follows in the attached image:

**Pyspark Error**

[image]

1. I have given Read & write permissions to the relevant folders by
   using the command chmod -R 777 /path/to/folder.
2. Also, when I run the *spark submit* command for Pi.py example on the cluster and locally; it runs well.
3. The problem persists only when stating file inputs

Please advice on a suitable solution for this issue. It persists on both MacOS and Windows systems and I have not got a suitable solution for the same

Here is the code snippet for `WC.py`

`WC.py` **code**

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995196/pyspark-how-to-show-current-directory